livepatch error?
Ubuntu 24.04 here, snapd version 2.62.
Every time i boot i get this in logs Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/"ID"/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
Looking at journal
journalctl -f -t canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
May 02 08:04:39 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Failed to refresh patch information: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/"ID"/updates" failed.
May 02 08:04:39 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/"ID"/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
May 02 08:05:09 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Client information is recent, not refreshing.
May 02 08:05:09 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Error in livepatch check state: check-failed.
May 02 08:05:10 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Task "refresh" completed succesfully after 1 retries.
May 02 08:22:03 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Client information is recent, not refreshing.
May 02 08:22:03 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Processing machine status.
May 02 08:22:03 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: Sending status update the livepatch server.
May 02 08:22:03 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: No updates available at this time.
May 02 08:22:03 Desktop canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1532]: No patch payload available.

When i try in firefox to post a req I get Method Not Allowed
canonical-livepatch status
last check: 6 minutes ago
kernel: 6.8.0-31.31-generic
server check-in: succeeded
kernel state: ✓ kernel series 6.8 is covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 6.8.0-31.31-generic
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
machine id: 

I need to understand this, is it due to beta and because the client is 24.04 can I install a stable one instead, this seems close to my errors https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/2044335?
Appreciate any insight.

I believe this is a long standing problem with Snap Store. You should be able to use killall snap-store && sudo snap refresh snap-store to fix it.

@graham killall snap-store gives "snap-store: no process found"  and sudo snap refresh snap-store gives "snap "snap-store" has no updates available"

oh well - another defect to report as a bug then but worth trying anyway if only to discount that possiility when reporting it.

I received this answer so the matter is closed:
https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/explanation/howitworks
https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels
Ubuntu 24.04 Noble does not have any supported kernels set for livepatch yet.
To refresh Ubuntu open terminal.
sudo snap refresh
